# Is there a way to individually number the output out a four dice roll in R?

Tags: r, dice

So if we roll four dice we get four different numbers. Is there a command in R that would let me call on each output from the vector individually?

So if the the dice roll gives (3,4,3,6) what command would let me call on one of those numbers individually later.

Comment: Please check stackoverflow for previous questions (as well as other sources [like this](https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-get-values-out-of-vectors-in-r/).

Answer (score 1):

```
fourDieRoll <- sample(1:6, 4, replace = TRUE)   
fourDieRoll[1]
fourDieRoll[2]
fourDieRoll[3]
fourDieRoll[4]
```

Comment: how could i use this command to return a vectors of the  sum the numbers that are >5 and keep the ones 5=< as they are? So in the example above i would want a vector = (10, 6)

Comment: Do you mean the other way around? Because sum numbers > 5 and keep <=5 as is would give the same as the original vector? If it is the other way around then `c(sum(fourDieRoll[fourDieRoll<=5]),fourDieRoll[fourDieRoll>5])` gives `[1] 10  6`